# Can Libre Office Writer set alternate page identifiers in an exported PDF?

Tags: pdf, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, page-numbers

Some PDF documents I use show a variety of identifiers in the "Page" widget for the PDF. For example, I'm looking at a mass-media college textbook right now, and the Page widget shows:

- "Cover" for the initial cover of the book.
- Roman numerals "i" to "xxx" for the 30 pages of front matter.
- Arabic numbers 1 to 1238 for the body of the book.

[image: PDF viewer page widget with Roman numeral visible]

Note that these match what's shown on the page itself in each case (Roman numerals vs. Arabic numerals, etc.)

Is it possible to use Libre Office Writer to export a PDF document that likewise shows different types of Page values depending on which part of the document you're in?

Note this question is different from [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/595056/libre-office-how-to-format-title-pages-for-book-avoiding-the-missing-blank-pag/595057), which is asking about page numbers printed on the document. In contrast, I am asking about the values showing in the PDF viewer Page widget, not on the pages of the document itself. I can make differently-formatted page numbers on the document pages, but exporting as a PDF shows all Page numbers in the PDF widget as sequential Arabic numerals from start to finish (and thus out-of-synch with what's printed on the document pages).

Comment: It doesn't look like libreoffice has an option to do this natively, but there are ways to change the page labels (what shows in pdf viwers) later, see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32048/renumber-pages-of-a-pdf) for some options.

Comment: @gepa: Thanks, that put me on the right track to just manually edit the PDF for the desired effect. If you post that as an answer I'll select it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, I don't think libreoffice has an option to do this natively.

If you want to change the page labels after you have created the PDF, there are several options, some are posted in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32048/renumber-pages-of-a-pdf).

In order to have an actual answer here, I am copying the main code from the best answer (using LaTeX) from that post here. Basically you create a file `scan_mod.tex` with this content:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}% or use 'letterpaper'
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
% Set lower case roman numbers (\Roman would be upper case):
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}
\includepdf[pages=1-3]{scan.pdf}
% Back to normal (arabic) numbers:
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}
% Reset page counter to 1:
\setcounter{page}{1}
\includepdf[pages=4-]{scan.pdf}
\end{document}
```

and then compile it with `pdflatex`:

```
# pdflatex scan_mod
```

I now found also an interesting answer on [this other post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/58315/edit-pdf-page-labels-in-pdf-tools) that works with `pdftk` which is a pretty common tool for manipulating pdf files. I didn't try this out personally, according to the post it should work with the Java variant of pdftk, starting from version 3.1.0 (I did try the LaTeX method above and that one definitely works for me). Again, here is the text from the original answer for completeness, to have it easily accessible here too:

First, create a file with the metadata you want, e.g.:

```
PageLabelBegin
PageLabelNewIndex: 1
PageLabelStart: 1
PageLabelPrefix: Cover
PageLabelNumStyle: NoNumber
PageLabelBegin
PageLabelNewIndex: 2
PageLabelStart: 1
PageLabelPrefix: Back Cover
PageLabelNumStyle: NoNumber
PageLabelBegin
PageLabelNewIndex: 3
PageLabelStart: 1
PageLabelNumStyle: LowercaseRomanNumerals
PageLabelBegin
PageLabelNewIndex: 27
PageLabelStart: 1
PageLabelNumStyle: DecimalArabicNumerals
```

Then apply it to the PDF file:

```
pdftk book.pdf update_info metadata.txt output book-with-metadata.pdf
```

Comment: Selected, thanks. I will say that I personally found it easier to manually edit the PDF code directly using Notepad++ (first link above, 2nd answer).